# Whenever I add an object its in the corner of the screen

Tags: java, swing, reference, coordinates, point

I thought i set the reference point to null but it seems like that is not happening. I chose a bunch of different coordinates for the object and it always is just in the top left hand corner. Sorry if this is stupid im new to this.

```java
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -240840600533728354L;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();


    }
}
```

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed -- nothing to do with this language

Comment: Hey Clayton, 
Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Naming your class `Window`, when there is already an AWT class with that name, is not a good idea. Then, the class is extending `Canvas`, but inside its constructor, it’s creating a new `JFrame`, adding an existing `Game` component, all without any relationship to the object of the `Canvas` extending type you’re currently creating. You should rethink that code. The whole operation would also work if it was not placed inside the constructor of the class extending `Canvas`…

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

needs to be called *after* the GUI has been rendered, usually after calling

```
frame.pack();
```

e.g.,

```
frame.add(game);
game.start();
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```